# Error: Imported targets not available for Boost version

Tags: c++, cmake, windows-10, zlib, taglib

I'm trying to build TagLib as per their installation guidelines:

The first part of the process:

1. Build the Makefiles:

   1. Open CMake GUI.
   2. Set Paths.
        "Where is the source code" and "Where to build the binaries"
        Example, Both would be: C:\GitRoot\taglib
   3. Tick: Advanced
   4. Select: Configure
   5. Select: Generator
   6. Tick: Use default native compilers
   7. Select: Finish
      Wait until done.
   8. If using ZLib, Scroll down.
        (to the bottom of the list of options ... should go over them all)

      1. Edit: ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR
      2. Edit: ZLIB_LIBRARY
   9. Select: Generate

When I do:
       4. Select: Configure

It starts processing, but then afterwards gives me the following errors:

```
CMake Warning at F:/libs/C/cmake-3.7.0-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:744 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  F:libs/C/cmake-3.7.0-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:848 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  F:/libs/C/cmake-3.7.0-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1435 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  ConfigureChecks.cmake:57 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:101 (include)
```

Why am I missing Boost, and how can I add it to get rid of the errors?

Comment: Do you have Boost installed on your system? Did you provide any hints to CMake about where it is installed (setting `BOOST_ROOT` or any other variable)?

Comment: It is not an *error*, it is just a **warning**. It means that for your version of Boost imported targets are not available (because the version is unknown or too old). But you still may use `${BOOST_LIBRARIES}` for refer to Boost libraries.

Comment: I have used [this tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#install-boost-build) to install it @wasthishelpful

Comment: This error is also triggered by using an old version of CMake.

Comment: @FrederikAalund: Old in what sense? And how can you overcome it without updating CMake?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: That doesn't really explain things. What are these imported targets? What's too old? How does this impact me?

Comment: @einpoklum: Yes, my comment doesn't explain everything, that is why it is a comment, not an answer. `How does this impact me?` - Depended. If configuration is successfull, it should work. Because the question doesn't provide an **error message**, I don't want to provide the answer which covers all possible errors. `What are these imported targets?` - see FindBoost module's [description](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindBoost.html). `What's too old?` - According to the script, less than 10.3300.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Fair enough, but - I don't want to ask my own basically-duplicate question about the same problem :-(

Comment: @einpoklum: You question needn't to be duplicate. If you have concrete error message - just post the question with it. As pointed by Frederik Aalund, old version of CMake could also be a reason for such version: `FindBoost.cmake` script, shipped with old CMake, may be unaware of newest Boost version. As you can see, the warning **alone** could have different reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake finds Boost but the imported targets not available for Boost version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123509/cmake-finds-boost-but-the-imported-targets-not-available-for-boost-version)