# CMake can not find boost libs

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am trying to build C++ progect uses boost and Cmake, but I have a problem with some libs[image]

I already added paths to "Environment Variables"[image]

And even added boost folder to "Path"[image]
But it doesn't work. May somebody give an advice!?

Comment: Well, did you build and install these two libraries?

Comment: Probably your CMake version is not new enough, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42124857/2799037. CMake 3.8.1 got further fixes regarding FindBoost.

Answer (score 0):

Your `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` should be a path to folder containing build boost libraries (typically something like `boost_1_64\stage\lib` filled with .dll and .lib files) while `boost_1_64\libs` contains source code. You need to build boost first and then set `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` accordingly.