# Cygwin’s CMake cant find all Boost dependencies?

Tags: boost, cmake, cygwin, gnu

I’m wondering why Cygwin’s setup.exe is providing CMake **1.6.2** and Boost **1.63.0**. As [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123509/cmake-finds-boost-but-the-imported-targets-not-available-for-boost-version) post describes, **Boost requires CMake 1.7.3** or newer to be found correctly.

I get almost the same warnings as in the linked Post. Here is the output of the build process with the highest available versions:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:743 (message):
    Imported targets not available for Boost version 106300
Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:842 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
    /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1395 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
    CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:743 (message):
    Imported targets not available for Boost version 106300
Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:842 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
    /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1395 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
    CMakeLists.txt:27 (find_package)


-- Boost version: 1.63.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /cygdrive/c/Users/Foo/Desktop/Programming/Simple-Web-Server/build
```

It would be interesting why Cygwin offers these versions as they seem of not fitting together? Or do they fit together and I discovered individual problems with my toolchain?

PS: Of course these are warning but `make` as the next command fails badly. Headers and its functions cant be found.
Im building on Win7, 64bit

Thank you very much in advance! Your cmake newbei

Comment: Please be mindful of version numbers, especially when you mark them in bold. Do you mean "CMake 3.6.2" and "CMake 3.7.3"? If so, then that is your answer. You cannot use Boost 1.63 without upgrading your CMake.

Comment: As you aware about [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123509/cmake-finds-boost-but-the-imported-targets-not-available-for-boost-version), the question should be like `Why Cygwin’s setup.exe provides CMake 1.6.2 and Boost 1.63.0, while  they are not fit together`. And **nothing above that** (no code and no error message are needed). But such question should be adressed to Cygwin maintainers, not here.

Comment: I doubt any `boost` version requires a specific cmake version. Have you installed the needed `libboost-devel` package ?