# boost program_options not found

Tags: boost, cmake

cmake - 3.8

I compiled and installed boost libraries in /usr/local/lib/, but unable to make cmake detect boost program_options through the command `find_package(Boost REQUIRED program_options)`. All other libraries `find_package(Boost REQUIRED thread system)` are found, and only adding program_options throws an error. I have tried quite a lot of things and kind of clueless - what is special about program_options.

```
-- Boost version: 1.63.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   filesystem
--   regex
--   serialization
--   unit_test_framework
--   iostreams
--   thread
--   system
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
```

The boost make was successful and it built the program_options library ( I can see it in the /usr/local/lib/ folder along with other boost libraries) . I just fail to understand, why would nt cmake find it?

```
Error : 
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.63.0

  Boost include path: /usr/local/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

          boost_program_options

  Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost.
```

Directory structure

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1558464 Aug 12 15:46 /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Aug 12 15:46 /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so -> libboost_program_options.so.1.63.0*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  658920 Aug 12 15:46 /usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options.so.1.63.0*
```

Comment: Post the error?

Comment: Is your CMake recent enough? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124857/2799037

Comment: @utopia updated the post.. also posting the directory structure of /usr/local/lib. I am really confused about the whole error.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this issue on Windows by adding `set(Boost_DEBUG ON) set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)` to my `CMakeLists.txt` file. This allowed CMake to find the correct version of boost and program_options.

My final CMakeList.txt looks something like this...

```
add_executable(test ${TEST_SRC})

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(Boost 1.30 COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED)

if(Boost_FOUND)
    target_include_directories(test PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    target_link_libraries(test ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

Answer (score -1):

After hours and hours of debugging, I gave up and found a work around. maybe it will help someone. In case cmake is doing nasty things, but you are sure, that your library is there in the boost library folder - just link the library explicitly .

```
target_link_libraries(TARGET lib1 lib2 ${Boost_LIBRARIES} libboost_program_options.so)
```

You may have to add `link_directories(/usr/local/lib/)` beforehand, in case the rpath does not contain /usr/local/lib.

Comment: downvote and run. I think it shud be made a criminal offence like hit and run.