# Required Boost Components with cmake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I was playing with the C++ Boost.Process library (v1.68) and am using cmake to compile.

I found it surprisingly difficult to know which cmake component (or even boost compiled library) a particular boost header/library requires. There are various similar Stackoverflow topics (some linked below), but most are very specific, fairly old, or end up in long discussions without really satisfying solution, and I am surprised that such a widely used collection of libs wouldn't have a simple section in the docs saying e.g. "Boost process requires X and Y" (or at least I could not find it).

I initially got tricked by [boost listing Boost.Process as "header only"](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries). Same e.g. at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45946466/8224596.
From what I can gather however, it seems to me that "header only" for boost only means "no additional code to compile apart from other boost components". I mistakenly thought the ["Categories"](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/) in the boost lib list were an indicator to which libs they depend on, but that turns out to be wrong as well.

Thus question remains open... How do I know which compiled libraries a boost library depends on?

The only **reliable solution I have found so far** is a boost lib tool "bcp" (inspired by [How to find out what dependencies (i.e other Boost libraries) a particular Boost library requires?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818717/how-to-find-out-what-dependencies-i-e-other-boost-libraries-a-particular-boost)). When I run `bcp --list boost/process/child.hpp` (which is the only header I use), I get a long list of files, ending with

```
[...]
boost/winapi/synchronization.hpp
boost/winapi/time.hpp boost/winapi/wait.hpp 
libs/filesystem/build/Jamfile.v2
libs/filesystem/src/codecvt_error_category.cpp
libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp
libs/filesystem/src/path.cpp
libs/filesystem/src/path_traits.cpp
libs/filesystem/src/portability.cpp
libs/filesystem/src/unique_path.cpp
libs/filesystem/src/utf8_codecvt_facet.cpp
libs/filesystem/src/windows_file_codecvt.cpp
libs/filesystem/src/windows_file_codecvt.hpp
libs/system/build/Jamfile.v2
libs/system/src/error_code.cpp
```

This would indicate that there are some dependencies on the boost components *filesystem* and *system* (for my v.1.68, I believe this would be different for 1.69 since system is now header only according to the docs).

This works, but the original topic is 8 years old. Is there a better way to get information about dependencies than `bcp` (e.g. a doc page I missed...)?

I the worst case, I hope this may help someone else going through the same process.

Thanks!

Comment: @JohnZwinck The title of the section says "Header-Only", but the list are the "The only Boost libraries that must be built separately".

Comment: https://pdimov.github.io/boostdep-report/boost-1.75.0/process.html

Comment: This question feels like a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818717/how-to-find-out-what-dependencies-i-e-other-boost-libraries-a-particular-boost - is there something different about what you're asking?

Comment: @JohnZwinck : No, that's also why I linked that duplicate in my question (as well as the answer). But the topic is over 8 years old, and the answer to the original topic was rather short with "use bcp".

Comment: I've posted a new answer suggesting using boost dep-report there.

Comment: @user7860670 : Thank you for the link! The dependency list does not seem to distinguish compiled from header-only ones though? E.g. `algorithm` and `asio` are not compiled boost libs, but are listed. On the other hand, `chrono` is listed in the "secondary dependencies" and is a compiled boost lib, but does not appear in the "libs" section of `bcp`?

Comment: Well, separation into header-only and compiled libraries are rather vague. chrono is one of those that is compiled but can be partially used as a header-only library. I'm not sure to which *"libs" section of bcp* you are referring to. I think chrono should be listed as a primary dependency though.

Comment: @user7860670 : I see, thanks for the clarification. When running `bcp`, some files are placed under "boost", and others under a "libs" path (see original question). I'm assuming the "libs" section is the ones I cannot build "header only" (e.g. as `Boost::headers` in the cmake case). I found the source of my confusion in this case : `bcp --list boost/process` does indeed return `chrono` as well. I was calling it on `process/child.hpp` specifically, which must not depend on `chrono`.