# cmake cannot find boost dlls build with layout=system

Tags: boost, cmake

For our project we build BOOST for Windows using the options `--layout=system` available for `b2`.

The dll produced will not carry any information and they will be plain vanilla dll names.

Example: `boost_iostream.dll` is produced instead of `boost_iostream-vc141-mt-gd-1_65_1.dll`.

Now `find_package(Bost 1.65.1 REQUIRED COMPONENTS iostream)` does not fail but when I try to link my executable using `Boost::iostream` cmake tells me that it cannot find file `boost_iostream-vc141-mt-gd-1_65_1.dll`

Is there a way to tell cmake that the dll does not carry versioning information as expected but are plain names?

Is `Boost::iostream` the right variable or there is another one specific for non versioned dll?

I cannot change the way boost is build unfortunately and I'd like to avoid using  `find_library` for all libs.

Comment: What's your CMake version? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124857/2799037

Comment: I am running cmake 3.11 I took a look at the FindBoost Module..for Windows it really expect the toolset version (-vc141-) depending on the compiler version. Unless I missed something there is no way to find the dll with different naming scheme.

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile Hello, I am facing the same problem; did you solve this issue?

Comment: @piwi Nope I haven't sorted out and i can't remember what I have done in that circumstance (as I am writing I don't have anymore with me the project I was working  back then )