# Cmake error: Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: boost, cmake

I am new to Cmake and Boost. I am now working on a program using cmake and need help.

System: windows 7
Cmake version: 3.16.0-rc1
Boost version: boost_1_71_0. And boost is installed through .exe file.
Gcc version: 4.8.1(rev5, Built by MinGW-W64 project)
Visual studio: vs 2015

When I run `cmake ..` in `build` dir, no error occurs. The output is:

```
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
Found Boost: C:/local/boost_1_71_0 (found version "1.71.0")  
Boost_Found Success!
Found OpenCV: C:/Users/gph/opencv/binaries (found version "3.4.5") 
Found OpenCV: C:/Users/gph/opencv/binaries (found version "3.4.5") found components: core highgui imgproc videoio 
Configuring done
```

But I want to use minGW to compile, so When I rum `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"`, error occured saying "Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR)". The output is:

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.1
Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Detecting C compile features
Detecting C compile features - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Detecting CXX compile features
Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at C:/Users/gph/cmake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: Boost_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/gph/cmake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Users/gph/cmake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2162 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:34 (find_package)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/gph/Desktop/libvibe++/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

How to solve the error when running `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"`? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this by adding sentence `set(BOOST_ROOT C:/local/boost_1_71_0)` before `find_package(Boost REQUIRED)` LOL...
But I still wonder why I need to add this.

Comment: looks like a bug, consider reporting https://github.com/boostorg/boost

Comment: in generic case after `b2 install` it must be detected automatically

Answer (score 5):

You can also set variables **BOOST_ROOT** during the creation of the cmake project (or CMake options in CLion and other IDE). For example:

```
mkdir buildtest; cd buildtest
cmake -DBOOST_ROOT=/you_path_to_boost/boost ..
cmake --build . -- -j 4
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem on Linux/Manjaro. Make sure you have boost installed, more specifically the boost development headers. I had the boost runtime libraries installed but not the headers. I installed those `sudo pacman -S boost` and it fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

After I solved this problem, thanks to ToughMind here, these problems occurred to me: _Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES and _Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES. What helped me was to update to the newest cmake verison and I got the answer from here: [CMake finds Boost but the imported targets not available for Boost version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123509/cmake-finds-boost-but-the-imported-targets-not-available-for-boost-version)