# g++: error: /usr/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework.a: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, hbase, thrift

I am stuck in compiling Thrift. I passed the ./Configure --host=arm process but was stuck in compiling with the Command "make". I have no idea how to solve that.

I went into the Makefile to make sure the path but still cannot solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a library, you can install it using the instructions here: [How to install Boost on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578499/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu) or here (see the final comment) [Could NOT find Boost (missing: unit_test_framework) (found version "1.71.0")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59189573/could-not-find-boost-missing-unit-test-framework-found-version-1-71-0)

Comment: sudo apt-get install automake bison flex g++ git libboost-all-dev libevent-dev
libssl-dev libtool make pkg-config  I ran this command before the ./configure actually

Comment: You will have want to locate where libboost is installed and specify it manually... first check /usr/lib (it shouldn't be there, but not a bad idea to check).  There is documentation here on how to specify the location of libboost, as sometimes it's in /usr/local apparently  : https://thrift.apache.org/docs/BuildingFromSource

Comment: I have to remind myself things may be more complicated on ARM.  I didn't have any issues: checking out the latest ( https://thrift.apache.org/download ), installing the deps `sudo apt-get install automake bison flex g++ git libboost-all-dev libevent-dev libssl-dev libtool make pkg-config`, running bootstrap.sh, then running ./configure in ubuntu on an x86.

Comment: If you've gone through those steps and it's giving you this issue, the only difference is I'm running on an x86 and your running on arm.  Which may mean libboost didn't install as a result, or it's placed somewhere that needs to be referenced directly in the configuration call.  If the order of installing the dependencies is different (like you started with bootstrap.sh->configure before installing the dependencies), then you may want to delete your configure file and regenerate it using bootstrap.sh .