# Use Boost as a git submodule with CMake

Tags: c++, git, boost, cmake, git-submodules

I want to use the Boost library for my C++ project (more precisely, I'm interested in the Boost Graph Library). I'd like it to be inside my git repository, as a git submodule, as it's done for every other dependency.

For example, if I want to start a project with `fmt` dependency as a git submodule, I do:

```bash
mkdir my_project
cd my_project
git init .
```

Then, I want to add `fmt` as a submodule, on tag `8.0.0`:

```bash
mkdir deps
git submodule add https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git deps/fmt
cd deps/fmt
git checkout 8.0.0
```

Then, I go back to my project's root folder:

```bash
cd ../..
```

And I create the following files:

- `main.cpp`

```cpp
#include <fmt/format.h>

int main() {
    fmt::print("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

- `CMakeLists.txt`

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test_boost)

add_subdirectory(deps/fmt)

add_executable(test_boost main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_boost fmt::fmt)
```

Then, we're able to build:

```build
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

And the binary works fine, expectedly printing `Hello, World!`, which is great.

Now if I want to add boost, version `1.77.0`:

```bash
git submodule add https://github.com/boostorg/boost deps/boost
git submodule update --init --recursive  # To get Boost's own submodules.
cd deps/boost
git checkout boost-1.77.0
cd ../..
```

Now I want to use this boost folder as dependency of my project, and this is where it gets tricky. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124857/2508277) that from version `1.77`, I should be able to use `find_package()` to do this, as it obseletes the `FindBoost` thing:

```cmake
find_package(Boost 1.77.0 REQUIRED CONFIG PATHS deps/boost/tools/boost_install)
```

But I get the following error:

```
-- Module support is disabled.
-- Version: 8.0.1
-- Build type: Debug
-- CXX_STANDARD: 11
-- Required features: cxx_variadic_templates
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Boost" that is compatible
  with requested version "1.77.0".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    /home/me/tests/boost_so/my_project/deps/boost/tools/boost_install/BoostConfig.cmake, version: unknown



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/me/tests/boost_so/my_project/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/me/tests/boost_so/my_project/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I tried other things as well, but I run into one of the following errors:

- The same one as above.
- CMake uses my Boost installation from `/usr/local`, which is not what I want.

I'm using CMake `3.17.2`. Is it possible to do this or am I missing something ?

Comment: you might need to build boost I imagine before `find_package` works? It'd probably make your life much easier to use a package manager like conan or vcpkg

Comment: I don't need to build `fmt` with the `add_subdirectory(deps/fmt)`, it's built if needed as part of my project build process, so I'm confused ...

Comment: You cannot use `find_package(Boost)` without **installing** the Boost. BTW, you could open the file [BoostConfig.cmake](https://github.com/boostorg/boost_install/blob/fb27358cbbbf6d5e224060e01dfda733b07e34a4/BoostConfig.cmake#L5) and find following lines: "# This CMake configuration file, installed as part of the Boost build and installation procedure done by `b2 install`, provides support for find_package(Boost)." If you need only a header-only part of the Boost, you could just add proper include directory.

Comment: ...don't. It's not worth the pain IME. Use vcpkg or Conan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution which seems quite simple. You can just `add_subdirectory()` as shown for `fmt`.

The complete `CMakeLists.txt` file looks like this:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(test_boost)

add_subdirectory(deps/fmt)
add_subdirectory(deps/boost EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

add_executable(test_boost main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test_boost fmt::fmt Boost::graph)
```

Then, you can see that [the following](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.graph-vertices-and-edges#ex.graph_07) compiles and runs fine:

```cpp
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    fmt::print("Hello, World!\n");

    enum { topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft };

    std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 4> edges{{
                                                     std::make_pair(topLeft, topRight),
                                                     std::make_pair(topRight, bottomRight),
                                                     std::make_pair(bottomRight, bottomLeft),
                                                     std::make_pair(bottomLeft, topLeft)
                                             }};

    typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS,
            boost::undirectedS> graph;
    graph g{edges.begin(), edges.end(), 4};

    std::cout << boost::num_vertices(g) << '\n';
    std::cout << boost::num_edges(g) << '\n';

    g.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs

```
Hello, World!
4
4
```

Comment: Do you know, how this can be done with odeint?

Answer (score 1):

That [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124857/12217229) also lists the version of Cmake you need to use . To be able to use `FindBoost` you need cmake version `3.21.3` or newer but you are using `3.17.2`