# linker issue compiling boost program_options with clang 14

Tags: c++, cmake, boost, linker

So I have minimal code `boost_version.cpp` that uses boost program_options:

```
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    boost::program_options::options_description desc("Allowed options");
    desc.add_options()
        ("help", "produce help message")
        ("input", boost::program_options::value<std::string>(), "input parameter");

    // parses cmd line options and stores them in a variable map
    boost::program_options::variables_map vm;
    boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
    boost::program_options::notify(vm);

    // if the help option is set, print the help message
    if (vm.count("help")) {
        std::cout << desc << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    // if the input option is set, print the input parameter
    if (vm.count("input")) {
        std::cout << "Input parameter was set to " << vm["input"].as<std::string>() << ".\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Input parameter was not set.\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Boost version: " << BOOST_VERSION / 100000 << "." 
              << BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 << "." 
              << BOOST_VERSION % 100 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am using boost program_options 1.74.0:

```
❯ locate libboost | grep boost_program_options
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_program_options.so.1.74.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_program_options-1.74.0/libboost_program_options-variant-shared.cmake
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/boost_program_options-1.74.0/libboost_program_options-variant-static.cmake
```

I want to build this using `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(BoostVersion)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(BOOST_ROOT "/usr/")
find_package(Boost 1.74.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
    add_executable(BoostVersion boost_version.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(BoostVersion ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()


message("BOOST_ROOT: ${BOOST_ROOT}")
message("Boost_DIR: ${Boost_DIR}")
message("Boost_INCLUDE_DIR: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message("Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
message("Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
```

And run this to build:

```
mkdir build && cd build
❯ cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang-14 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++-14 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-stdlib=libc++ -I /usr/lib/llvm-14/include/c++/v1" ..
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 14.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 14.0.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang-14 - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/clang++-14 - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found suitable version "1.74.0", minimum required is "1.74.0") found components: program_options 
BOOST_ROOT: /usr/
Boost_DIR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.74.0
Boost_INCLUDE_DIR: /usr/include
Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
Boost_LIBRARIES: Boost::program_options
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

```
❯ make
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/BoostVersion.dir/boost_version.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable BoostVersion
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/BoostVersion.dir/boost_version.cpp.o: in function `main':
boost_version.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int, unsigned int)'
/usr/bin/ld: boost_version.cpp:(.text+0x205): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, boost::program_options::options_description const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/BoostVersion.dir/boost_version.cpp.o: in function `boost::program_options::variables_map::operator[](std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const':
boost_version.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options13variables_mapixERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEE[_ZNK5boost15program_options13variables_mapixERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEE]+0x19): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::abstract_variables_map::operator[](std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/BoostVersion.dir/boost_version.cpp.o: in function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, char>::name() const':
boost_version.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEcE4nameEv[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEcE4nameEv]+0x48): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::arg'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/BoostVersion.dir/boost_version.cpp.o: in function `boost::program_options::typed_value<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, char>::xparse(boost::any&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&) const':
boost_version.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEcE6xparseERNS_3anyERKNS2_6vectorIS8_NS6_IS8_EEEE[_ZNK5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEcE6xparseERNS_3anyERKNS2_6vectorIS8_NS6_IS8_EEEE]+0x6c): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::validate(boost::any&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, int)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/BoostVersion.dir/boost_version.cpp.o: in function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::basic_command_line_parser(int, char const* const*)':
boost_version.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC2EiPKPKc[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcEC2EiPKPKc]+0x7d): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::cmdline(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/BoostVersion.dir/boost_version.cpp.o: in function `boost::program_options::basic_command_line_parser<char>::extra_parser(boost::function1<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&>)':
boost_version.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE12extra_parserENS_9function1INSt3__14pairINS4_12basic_stringIcNS4_11char_traitsIcEENS4_9allocatorIcEEEESB_EERKSB_EE[_ZN5boost15program_options25basic_command_line_parserIcE12extra_parserENS_9function1INSt3__14pairINS4_12basic_stringIcNS4_11char_traitsIcEENS4_9allocatorIcEEEESB_EERKSB_EE]+0x2a): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::detail::cmdline::set_additional_parser(boost::function1<std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&>)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/BoostVersion.dir/boost_version.cpp.o: in function `std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > boost::program_options::to_internal<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&)':
boost_version.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15program_options11to_internalINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEEENS2_6vectorIS8_NS6_IS8_EEEERKNS9_IT_NS6_ISC_EEEE[_ZN5boost15program_options11to_internalINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEEENS2_6vectorIS8_NS6_IS8_EEEERKNS9_IT_NS6_ISC_EEEE]+0x64): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::to_internal(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/BoostVersion.dir/boost_version.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEcEE[_ZTVN5boost15program_options11typed_valueINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEcEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::value_semantic_codecvt_helper<char>::parse(boost::any&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > > const&, bool) const'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/BoostVersion.dir/build.make:98: BoostVersion] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/BoostVersion.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

This was the error I received - What could cause this linker issue?

Comment: Can you try with CMake 3.19 or newer? Boost 1.74 is supported since CMake 3.19, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124857/2799037

Comment: is your boost installation compiled with the c++11 GCC ABI? You might want to try linking to `Boost::program_options` rather than using `include_directories` and `link_directories`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Could you show an example how to do it? I have a hunch that its due to mismatch of gcc (boost) and clang (code above)

Comment: @usr1234567 I was using CMake 3.22

Comment: ah, I hadn't noticed that you're using libc++. Did you build boost with libc++?

Comment: I used `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` so I am not technically sure if thats using libc++ or not. Is there a way to check?

Comment: It won't be, it'll be using the default standard library for your os. You'll need to build boost from source if you want to head off the beaten path