Problem adding Boost to Qt creator project
I'm trying to use Boost.Test in Qt Creator 6.4.1(msvc2019_64)(CMake 3.29.3)

cmake.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(DBSort VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set (BOOST_ROOT "F:/QTproj/Boost/boost_1_85_0/boost_1_85_0")

set (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set (Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
set (BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK OFF)

find_package (Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)

include_directories (SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable (UnitTest "unitTest.cpp")
target_link_libraries (UnitTest ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(DBSort
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        arrnumdialog.h arrnumdialog.cpp arrnumdialog.ui
        dialog.h dialog.cpp dialog.ui
        deletedialog.h deletedialog.cpp deletedialog.ui

        test_db
        unitTest.cpp



    )
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(DBSort SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    else()
        add_executable(DBSort
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(DBSort PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)

if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
  set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.DBSort)
endif()
set_target_properties(DBSort PROPERTIES
    ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS DBSort
    BUNDLE DESTINATION .
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(DBSort)
endif()


I use different libs of Qt and somehow the first include in mainwindow.h causes this error:
error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QPlainTextEdit': No such file or directory
Without including boost libs there are no problems running project
How do i properly add Boost libs to project or solve this error?

If you want to use Boost 1.85 (a couple of weeks old) you need CMake 3.29.3, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124857/2799037

With unsupported boost you may be able to add set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.85" "1.85.0") before the find_package(Boost REQUIRED) I used to do that long ago with unsupported versions.

It seems to me that unitTest.cpp should not be in DBSort. Removing it makes the compile and link succeed for me. If you really intend to link in the test suite, be sure to add the unit test library to the DBSort libraries just like for UnitTest, e.g.:
target_link_libraries (DBSort PRIVATE ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY})

Of course, the much broader version will work as well:
target_link_libraries (DBSort PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

Proof Of The Pudding
With the following minimal set

File CMakeLists.txt
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

 project(DBSort VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

 set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
 set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
 set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

 set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
 set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

 set (BOOST_ROOT "F:/QTproj/Boost/boost_1_85_0/boost_1_85_0")

 set (Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS ON)
 set (Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
 set (Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
 set (Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
 set (BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK OFF)

 find_package (Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework REQUIRED)

 include_directories (SYSTEM ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
 add_executable (UnitTest "unitTest.cpp")
 target_link_libraries (UnitTest ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

 find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)
 find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets)

 set(PROJECT_SOURCES
         main.cpp
         mainwindow.cpp
         mainwindow.h
         mainwindow.ui
 )

 if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
     qt_add_executable(DBSort
         MANUAL_FINALIZATION
         ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
         arrnumdialog.h arrnumdialog.cpp arrnumdialog.ui
         dialog.h       dialog.cpp       dialog.ui
         deletedialog.h deletedialog.cpp deletedialog.ui

         test_db
         unitTest.cpp
     )
 else()
     if(ANDROID)
         add_library(DBSort SHARED ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
     else()
         add_executable(DBSort ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
     endif()
 endif()

 target_link_libraries(DBSort PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)
 target_link_libraries(DBSort PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

 if(${QT_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 6.1.0)
   set(BUNDLE_ID_OPTION MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER com.example.DBSort)
 endif()
 set_target_properties(DBSort PROPERTIES
     ${BUNDLE_ID_OPTION}
     MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
     MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
     MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
     WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
 )

 include(GNUInstallDirs)
 install(TARGETS DBSort
     BUNDLE DESTINATION .
     LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
     RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
 )

 if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
     qt_finalize_executable(DBSort)
 endif()


File main.cpp
 #include <QApplication>
 #include <QMainWindow>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     QMainWindow window;
     window.show();
     return app.exec();
 }


File unitTest.cpp
 #define BOOST_TEST_MODULE MyTest
 #include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

 // declare a test suite:
 BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( test_suite1 ) 
 BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test1 )
 {
     BOOST_CHECK( 1 == 1 );
 }

 BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END() // test_suite1



The following reflects my Nix development environment

File flake.nix
 {
   description = "A basic flake with a shell";
   inputs.nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable";
   inputs.flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";

   outputs = {
     nixpkgs,
     flake-utils,
     ...
   }:
     flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system: let
       pkgs = nixpkgs.legacyPackages.${system};
     in {
       devShells.default = pkgs.stdenvNoCC.mkDerivation {
         name = "qtcreator shell";

         nativeBuildInputs = with pkgs; [
           cmake
           stdenv
           # qtcreator
           qt6.qtbase
           qt6.qtwayland
         ];

         env = {
           QT_QPA_PLATFORM = "wayland";
           Boost_DIR= "/home/sehe/custom/boost/stage/lib/cmake";
         };
       };
     });
 }



Then in the development shell, creating the project with:
touch {arrnumdialog,mainwindow,dialog,deletedialog}.{h,cpp,ui} test_db
cmake -B build . 
make -C build/

Compiles and links fine:

Adding #include <QPlainTextEdit> to mainwindow.cpp made no difference.
