CMake cannot find Boost on Windows 11 using MingW in Qt Creator
When I try to build a project I get the following error:
C:\_Project\Qt\testing2\CMakeLists.txt:24: ошибка: Could NOT find Boost (missing: thread chrono) (found suitable version
"1.85.0", minimum required is "1.85.0")

Call stack:
  C:/_Project/Qt/testing2/CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package)
  C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2393 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message)

It’s curious that using MSVC build in Qt everything works for me, but with the MinGW build it gives an error.
By the way for MinGW, I separately build libraries via .\bootstrap gcc and in the CMakeLists.txt I set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR path where are located .a libraries. Here is my CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(testing2 LANGUAGES CXX)
add_executable(testing2 main.cpp)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

set(BOOST_ROOT "C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0")
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib")
set(Boost_ARCHITECTURE -x64)


find_package(Boost 1.85.0 COMPONENTS thread chrono REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(testing2 ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(testing2 Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Core)


find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
install(TARGETS testing2
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)

I added Boost_DEBUG varibale, here is output:
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1706 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = "1.85.0;1.85"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1707 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "ON"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1708 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = "ON"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1709 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = "OFF"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1710 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1711 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1743 ] BOOST_ROOT = "C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1744 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = "C:\libraries\boost_1_85_0"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1745 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = "C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1746 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = "C:\Libraries\boost_1_85_0"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1747 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = "C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1748 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = "C:\libraries\boost_1_85_0\lib64-msvc-14.3"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1836 ] location of version.hpp: C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/boost/version.hpp
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1876 ] Boost_VERSION = "108500"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1877 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.85.0"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1878 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "108500"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1879 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1880 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "85"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1881 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1882 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1906 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = "lib"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1907 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:953 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-mgw11" (guessed)
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1943 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1995 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "-x64" (user-specified via Boost_ARCHITECTURE)
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2025 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2026 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-d"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2086 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib;C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/lib;C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib;C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/lib;C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/../lib;C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2087 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib;C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/lib;C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib;C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/lib;C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/../lib;C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2272 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_thread-mgw11-mt-x64-1_85;libboost_thread-mgw11-mt-x64;libboost_thread-mgw11-mt;libboost_thread-mt-x64-1_85;libboost_thread-mt-x64;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2327 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_thread-mgw11-mt-d-x64-1_85;libboost_thread-mgw11-mt-d-x64;libboost_thread-mgw11-mt-d;libboost_thread-mt-d-x64-1_85;libboost_thread-mt-d-x64;libboost_thread-mt-d;libboost_thread-mt;libboost_thread
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2272 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_chrono-mgw11-mt-x64-1_85;libboost_chrono-mgw11-mt-x64;libboost_chrono-mgw11-mt;libboost_chrono-mt-x64-1_85;libboost_chrono-mt-x64;libboost_chrono-mt;libboost_chrono-mt;libboost_chrono
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2327 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_chrono-mgw11-mt-d-x64-1_85;libboost_chrono-mgw11-mt-d-x64;libboost_chrono-mgw11-mt-d;libboost_chrono-mt-d-x64-1_85;libboost_chrono-mt-d-x64;libboost_chrono-mt-d;libboost_chrono-mt;libboost_chrono
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2272 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_RELEASE: libboost_atomic-mgw11-mt-x64-1_85;libboost_atomic-mgw11-mt-x64;libboost_atomic-mgw11-mt;libboost_atomic-mt-x64-1_85;libboost_atomic-mt-x64;libboost_atomic-mt;libboost_atomic-mt;libboost_atomic
-- [ C:/FILES/Qt/Tools/CMake_64/share/cmake-3.29/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2327 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_DEBUG: libboost_atomic-mgw11-mt-d-x64-1_85;libboost_atomic-mgw11-mt-d-x64;libboost_atomic-mgw11-mt-d;libboost_atomic-mt-d-x64-1_85;libboost_atomic-mt-d-x64;libboost_atomic-mt-d;libboost_atomic-mt;libboost_atomic


Set Boost_DEBUG variable before the find_package(Boost). That way CMake will print exact paths and exact filenames it searches for Boost. Compare these paths and names with the ones you actually have.

I added a flag. I've updated the topic above. Judging by the output, it correctly searches for libraries in BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = "C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib". But for some reason it doesn’t find it.

Im sure I separately build libraries via .\bootstrap gcc. And in "C:/libraries/boost_1_85_0/stage/lib" path there are .a libraries

What are the names of the libraries that you have?

libboost_thread-mgw13-mt-x64-1_85.a and libboost_chrono-mgw13-mt-x64-1_85.a for example. At the moment, I connected these 2 libraries manually by specifying the full path. For some reason, CMake do not see them in the directory.

To use Boost 1.85, you should use CMake 3.29.3, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124857/2799037

Judging by the cmake output you're using gcc 11 but the boost libraries have been built with gcc 13 so are incompatible

@usr1234567 if that was the issue there'd be a different error message

@AlanBirtles Sure, but this is the next problem waiting to occur.

@Danek: According to debug output, CMake searches files with names libboost_thread-mgw11-mt-x64-1_85, which uses mgw11 suffix. But suffix of the libraries you actually have is mgw13. You could set Boost_COMPILER variable to -mgw13, that way CMake will find your libraries. But I am unsure whether they will work for older gcc which you have.
