cmake doesn't find individual Boost components in /usr/include
cmake is driving me nuts again.
I want to use a few Boost packages. I would like to avoid depending on all of Boost.
This works:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(YOMM2 LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 1.5.2)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
message(STATUS "Boost is here: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

$ cmake -S . -B build
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.81.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.81.0")  
-- Boost is here: /usr/include
-- Configuring done (0.2s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/jll/dev/fpp/build```

And this doesn't:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(YOMM2 LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 1.5.2)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS mp11)
message(STATUS "Boost is here: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

$ cmake . -B build
CMake Error at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.81.0/BoostConfig.cmake:141 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "boost_mp11"
  (requested version 1.81.0) with any of the following names:

    boost_mp11Config.cmake
    boost_mp11-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "boost_mp11" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "boost_mp11_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "boost_mp11" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Boost-1.81.0/BoostConfig.cmake:262 (boost_find_component)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:594 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)

However, when I use vcpkg with this manifest:
{
  "name": "yomm2",
  "version": "1.5.3",
  "dependencies": [
    "boost-mp11"
  ]
}

Then it works:
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=$VCPKG_ROOT/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -S . -B build
-- Running vcpkg install
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-linux...
Compiler found: /usr/bin/c++
The following packages will be built and installed:
  * boost-cmake:x64-linux@1.85.0#1
...
-- Running vcpkg install - done
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Boost: /home/jll/dev/fpp/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/share/boost/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.85.0") found components: mp11 
-- Boost is here: /home/jll/dev/fpp/build/vcpkg_installed/x64-linux/include
-- Configuring done (0.8s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/jll/dev/fpp/build

The cmake I used in the examples above is version version 3.27.4.
I am under the belief (illusion?) that cmake will look for either the package config or the headers (that's what the doc seems to say). Am I doing something wrong?
[update] Hmmm, I see this in the trace:
/usr/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindBoost.cmake(2218):  set(Boost_${UPPERCOMPONENT}_HEADER ON )
/usr/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindBoost.cmake(2219):  message(WARNING No header defined for ${COMPONENT}; skipping header check  (note: header-only libraries have no designated component) )
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2219 (message):
  No header defined for mp11; skipping header check (note: header-only
  libraries have no designated component)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/jll/dev/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/share/boost/vcpkg-cmake-wrapper.cmake:11 (_find_package)
  /home/jll/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:811 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)


To use Boost 1.85 you need CMake 3.29.3 or newer, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124857/2799037

After some googling I found this, and usr1234567 pointed me to this.
It looks like a rabbit's hole to me, and I am beginning to think that I was conflating two different things anyway.
I want to provide a way for developers (or CI) to build my YOMM2 library quickly - meaning, no need to build all of Boost and its dependencies if Boost is not already installed. So I have two possible situations.
If Boost is installed system wide, cmake just needs to find Boost. It is up to the developer or sysadmin to ensure that the required libraries are there. In all likelihood, all of Boost will be there. That is the situation on my dev machine and in the docker image I use for GitHub CI.
Or the developer can use a package manager. With vcpkg, I can specify individual Boost libs. conan only provides a monolithic Boost. Anyway, I the dependencies are pulled by the package manager in this scenario, and CMakeLists.txt does not need to bother with it. That is the setup I use on Windows/MSVC.
